# Leaking memory in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory

My NavigationController has two controllers. When I go to the second controller, everything is good. However, when I return to the first controller and then go back to the second again, the amount of used memory increases (every time the second controller loads again, memory permanently grows). In the `viewDidLoad` method that handles the repeated loads, objects such as `_loadServicesView`, `_complexTableView`, and `_selectTypeCarView` are set to nil and then are created again. Why aren't these objects destroyed upon transition from the second controller to the first? Also, if they aren't destroyed, why are they being set to nil?

Here's the code related to the second controller:

```
@interface WCselectTypeViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) WCloadServices       *loadServices; 

@property (strong, nonatomic) WCloadView           *loadServicesView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) WCselectTypeView     *selectTypeView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) WCcomplexTableView   *complexTableView;

@end

@implementation WCselectTypeViewController


- (void)loadView
{
     [super loadView];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];

     if (!_loadServicesView)
     {
         _loadServicesView = [[WCloadView alloc] init];
         [_loadServicesView setDelegate:self];
         [self.view addSubview:_loadServicesView];
     }

     if (!_complexTableView)
     {
         _complexTableView = [[WCcomplexTableView alloc] initWithViewConfig:[WCappConfig getViewConfig]];
         _complexTableView.alpha = 0;
         _complexTableView.delegate = self;
         _complexTableView.dataSource = self;
         [self.view addSubview:_complexTableView];
    }

     if (!_selectTypeView)
     {
         _selectTypeView = [[WCselectTypeCarView alloc] initWithViewConfig:[WCappConfig getViewConfig] andType:[[WCorderStored sharedStore] getType]];
         [_selectTypeCarView setDelegate:self];
         [self.view addSubview:_selectTypeView];
     }
 }
```

Comment: How do you go from one controller to the next and back again? Is it using storyboard segues? Have you created a segue to go "back" (wrong)

Comment: I don't use storyboard or xib. Only programmatically created UIView

Comment: Make sure your "delegates" are "weak" and NOT "strong". "WCselectTypeViewController" is holding instance of "WCloadView" as "strong", and "WCloadView" "delegate" is set to "WCselectTypeViewController". Possible retain cycles.

Comment: So, can you answer my question? How do you go from one controller to the next, and back?

Comment: I go to the next controller - WCselectTypeViewController *selectTypeViewController = [[WCselectTypeViewController alloc] init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:selectTypeCarViewController animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the same (error/) behavior I experienced. Changing the VC's will put them on the stack; memory should decrease, if you use the back-arrow, doesn't it?

Instead of the navigation controller I used a PageViewController.

This is my working solution:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    // Create the data model
    _pageTitles = @[@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5"];
//    _pageImages = @[@"page1.png", @"page2.png", @"page3.png", @"page4.png"];

    // Create page view controller

    self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

    PageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

    // Change the size of page view controller
    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 30);

    [self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

}

```
- (PageContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{

    if (([self.pageTitles count] == 0) || (index >= [self.pageTitles count])) {
        return nil;
    }
    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.


//    pageContentViewController.imageFile = self.pageImages[index];

    PageContentViewController *pageContentViewController;
    if (index == 0){
        pageContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailView1"];
        pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index;
    }
    else if (index == 1){
        pageContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailView2"];
        pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index;
    }
    else if (index == 2){
        pageContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailView3"];
        pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index;
    }
    else if (index == 3){
        pageContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailView4"];
        pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index;
    }
    else if (index == 4){
        pageContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailView4"];
        pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index;
    }

    return pageContentViewController;

}
```

Comment: I use _complexTableView, _loadServicesView and _selectTypeView instead xib or storyboard.

Comment: Nevertheless the issue is the same I guess; Do you have the navigation bar enabled in the navigation controller? If so, there should be that back arrow; using that, the VC correctly gets destroyed, otherwise the VCs get stacked.
Here is my question facing the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23846686/memorymanagement-with-uinavigationcontroller

Comment: I seem guessed where an error according to your message
in appDelegate I do UIBarButtonItem * to backButtonItem = [by [UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                      target:self action:nil];
    navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.backBarButtonItem = backButtonItem;
but having commented out it, the problem wasn't solved